# For loop doesent work while trying to add elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ok so i have a sidenav menu and it has 3 levels and the second layer has openers but the third layer doesent so i have to add openers like this ▼ via javascript but there are too many of them so i had to use a for loop too give each of the second layers an opener,i already created an object named opener2 like this

```js
var opener2=document.createElement("span");
opener2.classList.add("opener");
```

aand then here is the for loop that doesent work

```
for(var q=0; q < $('.menu-block').length; q++){
if($('.menu-block')[q].childElementCount >=2){$('.menu-block')[q].before(opener2)};};
```

so let me explain menu-block is the part that contains both the opener and an item of the second layer,like there are 5 of them and each are different from each other,if there are 2 elements inside the second layer items menu block,that means this for loop shouldnt add an opener.Soo what should i do?

Edit:The problem is solved thx for your help guys

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: i mean the if part works,like when i put 1 or 2 or anything besides q it works but when i try to automate it with for loop it just gets stucks and in the end it does nothing like it doesent add anything

Comment: Errors in the console? Please edit your question and insert a runnable snippet using the toolbar, which we can run, and which demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var q=0; q < $('.menu-block').length; q++) {
if($('.menu-block')[q].childElementCount >=2){
 let opener2=document.createElement("span");
 opener2.classList.add("opener");
 $('.menu-block')[q].before(opener2)};
};
```

Declare the object declaration inside the for loop or else the same element will get appended again and again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have created only *one* `span` element, so this will not magically create new ones. If you have a second call to `.before`, it will actually *move* the `span` from its previous insertion point to the current.

It is not so efficient that you repeatedly reselect the elements with the ".menu-block" selector. Just do that once, and use `.each` to iterate over that collection.

Also, you are mixing jQuery code with jQuery-less code, which is a pity. If you use jQuery, you should not have to use things like `document.createElement`.

So here is how you could do it:

```
$('.menu-block').each(function () {
    if (this.childElementCount >= 2) {
        $("<span>").addClass("opener").insertBefore(this);
    }
});
```